# Use variable inside of command in Makefile

Tags: bash, make, makefile

Let's say the LINK variable contains the following: `1a2b3c`. I'd like to display `Full path: /home/build/1a2b3c`.

PWD is currently at `/home`;

I can't get the following to work:

```
@echo "Full path: $(readlink -f build/$(LINK))"
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work, as long as the variable `$LINK` is exported. So make sure to run `export LINK` before running make.

Example:

```
$ printf "test:\n\t@echo \"\$(LINK)\"" > makefile #Make the test makefile
$ LINK='1a2b3c'
$ make

$ export LINK
$ make
1a2b3c
```